# Finding difference of days from start and end using joda?

Tags: java, json, jodatime

I want to find out from the startDate and endDate how many days is it. From my json response, I can get back these in String:

```
String startDate = "Fri, 10 Jan 2015 23:10:04 +0000";
String endDate = "Mon, 26 Jan 2015 11:26:04 +0000";
```

How would I use joda to calculate and get me back the correct number of days (hence: numOfDays = endDate - startDate) ??

```
public int getNumberOfDays(String startDate, String endDate) {
    String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +xxxx";
    .....

    // quick test on startDate
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(startDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern));
    System.out.println("The day should be 10 but it yields 9 --> " + dateTime.getDayOfMonth());

}
```

Comment: String startDate = "Fri, 10 Jan 2015 23:10:04 +0000";
String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +xxxx";

Does anyone know if the pattern is correct? I am struggling to parse the 'EEE' correct and I don't know if it has to do with that or the ',' comma. If I remove "Fri," hence the "EEE," then I am able to get the day (10) correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Days** Class of Joda Library

```
Days days=Days.daysBetween(startDate.toLocalDate(), endDate.toLocalDate()).getDays();
int noOfDays=days.getDays();
```

As an alternative we can also ues **Java 8** ***Date and Time API***

```
public void days_between_two_dates_in_java_with_java8 () {

    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now();

    long days = Period.between(startDate, endDate).getDays();


    // or 

    long days2 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);

}
```